# Code fails to continue when user input is evaluated

Tags: c, arrays, string, compare, conditional-statements

I have some code where I ask a user if they would like to continue. If they type:

- `no`, it asks for another input.
- `yes`, it continues to the next code block.
- neither, it asks the user to choose `yes` or `no` again.

The problem is, when I type `yes`, the code stops.

Here is the main block of the code:

```
int main(){
    int degree=0, ctr, i;
    int factorsp[degree+1], factorsq[1000], coeff[degree+1], answers[degree+1];
    char deg[1000], option[5]="YES", p[1000], q[1000], coeffs[1000], choice[10]="no";

    while(option!="NO"){
        while(degree==0){
            degree=degfunc(degree);
            while(strcmp(choice,"no")==0 && degree!=0){
                printf("The highest degree will be %d.(Yes/No)" ,degree);
                fgets(choice, 4, stdin);
                sscanf(choice, "%s", choice);

                for (i=0; i<strlen(choice);i++){
                    choice[i] = tolower(choice[i]);
                }

                if(strcmp(choice,"yes")==0){
                    printf("hi");
                }

                if(strcmp(choice,"no")==0){
                    degree=0;
                    printf("wew");
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    printf("\007Error! That is not a valid answer!\n");
                    strcpy(choice,"no");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This `sscanf(choice, "%s", choice);` looks critical, as source and destination overlapp, are the same in fact.

Comment: Also shouldn't the (second) `if(strcmp(choice,"no")==0){` be `else if(strcmp(choice,"no")==0){`?

Comment: oh yeah hahaha thanks. but even after i changed it, i still had problems. I cahnged my fgets and sscanf to scanf and still had problems

Comment: 0) `while(option!="NO"){` use `strcmp` 1) `NO`, `No` and `no` are different. 2) `fgets(choice, 4, stdin);` -->  `fgets(choice, 10, stdin);` (5 or more)

Answer (score 1):

This does not do what you think it does:

```
while(option!="NO") {
```

You must use strcmp to compare strings. In addition you probably meant

```
else if(strcmp(choice,"no")==0){
```

instead of `if(strcmp(choice,"no")==0){` if you wanted to test for three outcomes, yes, no, neither of them.

Next, what's the `sscanf` supposed to do? If you meant to remove the newline that `fgets` stored in `choice[]`, then why not look for it and replace it with a '\0'?

Comment: Also, in C `"NO" != "no"`.

Comment: @Jongware Pun intended? :-)